# How to set service key file for a single invocation of "gcloud" utility?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

Is there a way to set a custom service key file for a single invocation of "gcloud" tool without running `gcloud auth activate-service-account` ?

Similar to the related "gsutil" tool where this can be easily done using `-o` option:
`gsutil -o Credentials:gs_service_key_file=path/to/credentials_file.json arg1 arg2 ...`

Answer (score 2):

I've not tried this but, it appears, yes:

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/

```
gcloud --account="..."
```

You can authenticate multiple service accounts using `gcloud auth activate-service-account` and you can enumerate the list with `gcloud auth list`.  You would then switch commands between them using the `account` flag.

Until your question, I'd always done this rather tediously through reconfiguring `gcloud config set account ...`, so thanks for helping me learn something new!

Comment: Thanks. This solution is not exactly what I was looking for, because it needs pre-configured set of accounts, but it is better than nothing.